# MongoDB command counting how many times a value in field A appears with distinct value in field B(or MySQL command acceptable)

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I have a collection in MongoDB, and suppose the data is:

_id  |  doc_name   | serial_number

1 | a | abc

2 | b | abc

3 | a | abc

4 | a | def

5 | c | def

6 | b | abc

I want to count how many times "serial_number" appears with distinct "doc_name". In this case, it should be:

abc|2

def|2

and I want to save the results into another collection.

How can I do this?

MySQL command is also acceptable, since I can use the MySQL --> MongoDB translator..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: next time post a real  documents as {doc_name:'c',serial_number:'def'}
and not  1 | a | abc
so we can check

Answer (score 2):

its easy with our lil' buddy mongo. use a mongo aggregation using $sum within the [$group operator.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

it appears the your sample output is incorrect. either

```
abc|4
def|2
```

or

```
a|abc|2
b|abc|2
a|def|1
c|def|1
```

the 1st is

```
db.collection.aggregate(
     [{$group: {_id: "$serial_number",: {$sum: 1} }]
)
```

the 2nd is

```
db.collection.aggregate(
     [{$group: {_id: {"$serial_number", "$doc_name"},: {$sum: 1} }]
)
```

and then ill defer to @nickmilon for the $out operator (that ive never used). cool

```
{ $out : 'output_collection' }
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I want to count the number of DISTINCT doc_names that appears with a serial_number. so the two a|abc count as 1. so the result that I want to get should be the one stated in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what about this ? :

```
db.your_collection.aggregate( 
    [
     {
        $group: {_id: {doc_name:'$doc_name', serial_number:'$serial_number'},
            'count': {'$sum': 1}}
    },

     {
        $group: {_id: '$_id.serial_number',
            'count': {'$sum':  1}}
    },

    { $out : 'output_collection' }
    ]
```

)

- remark //{ $out : 'output_collection' } to see the results :

{ "_id" : "abc", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "def", "count" : 2 }